# OS X Background Fetch Equivalent

Tags: macos, background-process, safari-extension, background-fetch

I'm familiar with the Background Fetch in [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh) but I was wondering if there is an equivalent for OS X apps.

My application is bundled with a Safari App Extension that needs to update frequently. Auto update does not look like it's supported from what I've read in the forums on the App Extensions since it's bundled to the OS X app. I have a shared data storage between the app and the extension so my ideal solution would be having the app run (in the background wether the user has it open or not) periodically check for the latest version. Then when the user is actually engaging with my extension it will notify the user of the update. This is why a solution like [Sparkle](https://sparkle-project.org/) is not desired.

I have everything down, but I'm lost on running the background process. Appreciate any help or creative solutions!

Comment: Hey, any updates? Did you find some solution to this? I'm struggling to receive real-time notifications to CoreData paired with CloudKit at Safari extension too